# Error while Installing Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC for ASP.NET Core project

Tags: telerik, asp.net-core, bower, telerik-mvc, bower-install

I am trying installing UI for ASP.NET MVC for ASP.NET Core. I am following these guidelines here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-core/getting-started

I was able to install Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core": "2016.3.914" dependency using Nuget Packages.

However having trouble installing client side resources (STEP 6)
The step 6 says "Copy the js and styles folders from the telerik.ui.for.aspnetmvc archive to wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui." however it does not mention how do we get these resources to copy from?

1>Should we download these client side resource as separate download ( like we do for traditional ASP.NET MVC)?
2> I tried using bower to install these resources however I get error below during installation

> bower : bower bower-kendo-ui#*    invalid-meta The "main" field cannot
>   contain minified files At line:1 char:1
>   + bower install https://bower.telerik.com/bower-kendo-ui.git
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bower bower-ken... minified files:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: Did you read the documentation about errors during bower restore? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/bower-install#restore-fails-in-aspnet-core-mvc-rc-projects-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @Tseng Yes, I read that However the error I am getting is different. I still  added a new entry `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` as suggested but that did not resolve the issue

Answer (score -1):

I found that there was another step in addition to loading the package using Nuget, I had to manually copy files to the wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui folder.

Below is a Forum post that I found helpful on the Telerik site.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/ui-for-asp-net-core-vs-ui-for-asp-net-mvc

Below are the instructions that I followed:

Log into your Telerik.com account, go to the Downloads section and download the UI for ASP.NET MVC installation. Install it and you'll find the Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core.2016.3.914.nupkg package inside

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for ASP.NET MVC R3 2016\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc6 folder.

This NuGet installation contains the files compiled against ASP.NET Core framework.